# Comparing 3 Objects

Tags: c#, comparison, comparator, icomparable, icomparer

I am coding a generic Binary Tree in C#.

In one portion of my application I need to sort in order of distance.

from A to C and B to C.

something like this:

```
if ((A->C) == (B->C))  
    return 0;
else if((A->C) < (B->C))
    return -1;
else
    return 1;
```

But the problem is, I can only compare between 2 objects... and I need some kind of comparator.

Creating a class like "distance between start and end" is a correct solution? I Think it creates too much garbage.

Any solution?
Thanks ;-)

edit:

```
public AvlNode<T> _left, _right;
public Stack<T> _obj;

(...)

public AvlNode<T> Insert(T obj, IComparer<T> iComparer)
    {
        if (iComparer.Compare(obj, _obj.Peek()) > 0)
        {
            _right = (_right != null) ? _right.Insert(obj, iComparer) : new AvlNode<T>(obj);
            return Balance();
        }
        else if (iComparer.Compare(obj, _obj.Peek()) < 0)
        {
            _left = (_left != null) ? _left.Insert(obj, iComparer) : new AvlNode<T>(obj);
            return Balance();
        }
        else
        {
            _obj.Push(obj);  // distance already exists but object may be different, that's why I use a stack...
            return this;
        }
    }
```

I dont have a working IComparer...

Edit:

Problem Solved, now I have a working IComparer!

```
public class ObjectDistanceComparer : IComparer<EraObject>
{
    Vector3 _position;


    public ObjectDistanceComparer(Vector3 position)
    {
        _position = position;
    }

    int IComparer<EraObject>.Compare(EraObject obj1, EraObject obj2)
    {
        float d1 = (_position - obj1._position).LengthSquared();
        float d2 = (_position - obj2._position).LengthSquared();
        return (d1 == d2)? 0 : (d1 < d2)? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

Thanks ;-)

Comment: You could implement a generic method in a class to compare three things at once, I suppose, but I think it's probably better to do the comparisons in sequence.   You'd compare A to B, then B to C, and you'd know the exact order, right?  (Assuming that comparison is defined for the implementing classes in a sane way, ie, that it's transitive.  And I think that's a fair assumption to hoist on the users of your class.)

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have for the tree and how you intend to "sort" it from three objects. It isn't quite clear how that's supposed to work. Show an example tree and its "sorted" form.

Comment: This is not related to your question, but IMHO it's better to do not use `_` in definition of member variables. especially public ones.

Comment: @ Saeed Amiri, I learned like this with java, how do you define member variables correctly? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could add extra property to your Node class:

```
public class Node : IComparable
{
   Node Parent{get;set;}
   Node LChild {get;set;}
   Node RChild {get;set;}
   Node C {get;set;}

   public int CompareTo(object o)
   {
      // Now you passed C in your object, do stuff ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This code written before OP shows code, so they are not the same, but very similar way is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Distance
{
int Source {get;set;}
int Destination{get;set;}
int Value{ 
          get{ return Math.Abs(Destination - Source);}
         }
}
```